# Can we see installation logs while installing a managed package?

Tags: managed-package, postinstall

I have an install handler in the package which inserts certain records post installation. But when I install the managed package neither do I see any logs nor the records are inserted. Also I have put debugs in my installer class which do not show up in developer console. Could anyone help on this?

Comment: Do you have access to the [LMA application](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_lma.meta/workbook_lma/lma_intro.htm)? If so, use that to log into the org before installing the managed package. Of course, that would likely only work if you were upgrading an existing package.

Comment: Another option is that Salesforce support can open up the managed package debug logs for you with consent from the package creator. As the creator that should be an easier task.

Comment: Ensure the packing org has defined the "Notify on Apex Error" field.

Comment: Hi @Kanika, did logging install script work for you? I tried myself setting up debug log at subscriber org. and running the managed package update(Beta) and checking logs from Debug logs from LMA subscriber access, but seems it did not log install post script for me. Any thoughts? Thanks.